# Extension for replacing by index set

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to add an extension for `Array` to replace elements by index set:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func replace(newElements: [Element], at indexes: IndexSet) {
        //implementation here
    }
}
```

And an example of using:

```
var set: IndexSet = [2, 1]
var array = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
array.replace(newElements: ["@", "%"], at: set) // custom method from future extension
print(array) //Prints ["0", "%", "@", "3", "4"]
```

But I have trouble with getting element from `IndexSet` by index. How I can do it? Or maybe you know more elegant solution for replacing elements in array. I'm using `IndexSet` instead `Array<Int>` because later I'll use it for replacing sections in `UITableView`.

Comment: `IndexSet` is a Set, which means it doesn't preserve ordering. It's not well suited for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using `[Int]` instead of `IndexSet`, when you use this, you have to use sth like `indexes.index(indexes.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)` to access the index, very annoying, I advised just use `[Int]` like other array function and throws error when the value is out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

As @Alexander mentions above it makes little sense to use an IndexSet as this is not ordered. What you probably want is an array of `Int`s for each index. That should leave you with something like this:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func replace(newElements: [Element], at indexes: [Int]) {
        for (index, position) in indexes.enumerated() {
            guard position < count else {
                // error handling
                return
            }

            remove(at: position)
            insert(newElements[index], at: position)
        }
    }
}
```